# Not Able To get the token Id in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using below code to register new user in Flutter Application with Firebase as backend, but I am not able to retrieve the token id in my application, when I tried to save it the firestore database it is storing it as `null`.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: emailInputController.text,
                      password: pwdInputController.text)
                      .then((currentUser) =>
                      Firestore.instance
                          .collection("users")
                          .document(currentUser.user.uid)
                          .setData({
                        "id": currentUser.user.uid,
                        "tokenId": currentUser.user.getIdToken(),
                        "fullname": fullNameInputController.text,
                      })
```

I receive this in my logs about the tokenId

> Invalid argument: Instance of 'Future<'IdTokenResult'>'

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the official documentation [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User.html#getidtoken), it actually returns a promise, so you won't be able to directly access the value. You will need to await the value to be loaded and them manage it. You will need to handle as in the below code sample:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(user => {
        if (user != null) {
           user.getIdToken().then(token => {
             //handle token
           }
        }
});
```

In case you want a more direct way, the below line should work for you too.

```
var token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getIdToken();
```

**While this codes are untested,**, I believe they should help you have handle the promise, you should have the value and saving it in your database should not face any more issues.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: I am receiving this in my logs `Invalid argument: Instance of 'Future<IdTokenResult>'` , it is not working

Comment: Hi @MarkDavids have you tried the `await` that I mentioned? This error is related to the fact that the token results are a promise and you need to use `await` to handle the results.

Comment: Yes, I did so, still the same problem . If try to use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getIdToken().toString()` it stores in the database as `Instance of 'Future<IdTokenResult>'`

Comment: You should not use it like this, you need to use the `await` before. Using the `toString()` won't work. If you already used the code that I provided, could you please update your question with your new try outs and with where you added the code? This way not just me, but the whole Community will be able to check it, due to the fact that using the `await` or the other method that I mentioned are used to handle and avoid this error. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466751/dart-error-unhandled-exception-e-flutter-5079-invalid-argument-instance-o) as well.