# Firebase Storage error : Invalid argument: Instance of '_File'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to firebase storage but I get this error when trying to upload:

```
  Invalid argument: Instance of '_File'
```

This is a debug console print of the file taken through image picker, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
I/flutter (21742): File: '/data/user/0/com.example.weepay_pos/cache/image_picker175751972.jpg'
```

Here is my code:

```
Future getImage() async {


    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
        if (pickedFile != null) {
            _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
            print(_imageFile);
        } else {
            print('No image selected.');
        }
    });
}
Future upload() async {

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child("$_imageFile" + DateTime.now().toString());
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_imageFile);
    uploadTask.then((res) {


        print("Image Uploaded");
    });

}
```

Comment: Not sure if you are using a variable _File but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466751/dart-error-unhandled-exception-e-flutter-5079-invalid-argument-instance-o) can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a string variable here. It is an instance of File.

```
Reference ref = storage.ref().child("imageFileName" + DateTime.now().toString());
```

Comment: im sorry  dont follow you

Comment: coud you please explain

Comment: Here you tried to use an instance of file: "$_imageFile"

But it requires a string variable in here. So, you should not use that variable. You can type any string value in here.

Comment: i changed that to a string, just some random numbers and I go the same error

Comment: it even says this is the invalid value in the exception "/data/user/0/com.example.weepay_pos/cache/image_picker1937673433.jpg"